# extract column names from dataframe according to data in python

Tags: python, dataframe, metrics

I have a dataframe looks like this

```
    a   b   c
a  0.3 0.2 0.9 
b  0.9   1 0.8
c  0.2 0.9 0.5
```

I want to extract the column name if the corresponding value is greater or equal to 0.9.

The result dataframe looks like this:

```
a  c 
a  a b 
c  b
```

Comment: What have you done so far and what's the problem you faced?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
In [29]: df.ge(0.9).apply(lambda x: df.columns[x].tolist(), axis=1)
Out[29]:
a       [c]
b    [a, b]
c       [b]
dtype: object
```